# paint event in c#.Net

Tags: c#, graphics, paint

I have the following controls in my application,

- A user control consists of a panel
- An 'Open' button
  I use Paint event to draw the image(browsed and selected using OpenFileDialog) on the user control. It works fine for first image. If I use the OpenFileDialog to open second image, the part with the size of OpenFileDialog is not shown in the control. Is it problem using with Paint event ?

Comment: Have you considered using PictureBox to draw your image instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for control that you handle its paint event.if the control is you usercontroll
Just do it after dialog:

```
myUserControl.Invalidate()
```

Invalidate method calls paint event for specified control again automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to manually call the update method of your panel after the OpenFileDialog is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better:

```
//you have a picturebox in the form pictureBox1
// openFileDialog ofd

if (ofd.ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.pictureBox1.Image = new BitMap(ofd.FileName);
}
```